# Tkinter: Updating Images in labels that aren't directly accessible

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

In my GUI, i wanted to display an image that changes depending on some value. The image would change between `self.img1` and `self.img2`. I created separate classes for the container and the pages. The container is defined as such:

```
class Gui(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = TRUE)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)


        self.MyReading = StringVar()

        self.redpic = Image.open("red.png")
        self.redpic = self.redpic.resize((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.greenpic = Image.open("green.png")
        self.greenpic = self.greenpic.resize((100,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.redpic)
        self.img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.greenpic)

        self.frames={}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
```

And the page displaying the image:

```
class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = Label(self, text="StartPage")
        label.grid()
        label1 = Label(self, textvariable = controller.MyReading)
        label1.grid();

        self.label4 = Label(self, image = controller.img1)
        self.label4.grid();
        self.label4.image = controller.img1

        button1 = Button (self, text = "Show PageOne", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid()
```

It is currently displaying `img1`. Now, to instantiate the GUI:

```
root = Gui()
update_reading()
root.mainloop()
```

`update_reading()` updates my other labels defined with `StringVar()`. I was wondering how would I go about updating `label4` (which shows the image) if I can only instantiate/get access to `Gui()`? I only know that I could change the `label4` through `configure()`. Is there a `textvariable` equivalent for images?

**EDIT**: I forgot to put the logic that I wanted to implement. It is basically:

```
If foo == TRUE:
  --change the image to img1--
else:
  --change the image to img2--
```

for some `foo` that exists outside of `Gui`.

**EDIT2**: Following through a previous comment's logic, I made some small changes to the code In the `Gui`:

```
class Gui(Tk):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.ColorVar = DoubleVar()
```

And within `StartPage()`, the changes are:

```
class StartPage(Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    controller.ColorVar.trace("w",self.IdkChief(controller))

  def IdkChief(self, controller):
        global val1
        if float(val1) < 2.50 :
            self.label4.configure(image = controller.img2)
            self.label4.image = controller.img2
        else:
            self.label4.configure(image = controller.img1)
            self.label4.image = controller.img1
```

Then the changes on `ColorVar` is defined in `update_reading()`as such:

```
def update_reading():
    global val1
    root.ColorVar.set(val1)
    root.after(100,update_reading)
```

Where `val1` is a changing float value. I decided to change it from a boolean logic to a float one to increase flexibility. It would then throw me a generic error

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

This error would repeat until the GUI is closed.

Comment: *"through configure()"*: It's the same: `.label4.configure(image=controller.img2)`.

Comment: Yea, I meant `label4.configure(image=controller.img2)`. But I was wondering if there   is a way for me to do the changing outside of class `StartPage` automatically(without pressing a button and calling a class function)

Comment: Can you change `foo` to `BooleanVar`? If yes, then you can use `foo.trace('w', callback)` to call the `callback` whenever `foo` is updated.  Inside `callback` you can then update the image of `Label4` based on the value of `foo`.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, I create a `BooleanVar()`, say `ColourVar` within my `Gui()` class, which is then passed to my `StartPage()` class. I write within my `StartPage()` class the variable trace and the `callback` function. I can just then update the `ColourVar` with a `Tk.after()` command. When I did this, it would just give me a generic error of `NoneType` object being not callable. The `callback` seems to run only once before the error would occur.

Comment: You passed the result of `self.IdkChief(controller)` as the callback parameter of `trace()`, so callback is None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tkinter variable `trace` function to set up a callback function to be executed whenever the variable is updated.  Inside the callback function, you can then update the label based on the value of the variable.

Below is sample code blocks (based on your posted code design) to achieve your goal:

```
class Gui:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.ColorVar = DoubleVar()
        ...

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        # register a callback to be executed whenever variable is modified
        controller.ColorVar.trace('w', lambda *args: self.IdkChief(controller))

    def IdkChief(self, controller):
        img = controller.img1 if controller.ColorVar.get() < 2.5 else controller.img2
        self.label4.config(image=img)
```